# Magento 2.3.1 Installation fails - An error occurred during execution; please try again later

Tags: magento2, installation

I try to install the latest Magento 2 version which is 2.3.1 - Full Release (ZIP with no Sample Data)

I unchecked any optional extension in the advanced settings during the installation process.

I get `http://example.com/setup/index.php/install/start 500 (Internal Server Error)` logged into the chrome developer console.

[image: chrome developer tools]

It stucks at exactly 15% on Module 'Magento_InventorySales'.

I get `Class 'Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\RouteMatch' not found in /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/Segment.php:388`

[image]

I also tried to download the project via composer, but this made no difference.

Any solutions?

---

**Update:**

I get this error

```
[Fri Mar 29 13:28:18.886195 2019] [lsapi:error] [pid 1993698:tid 47071602472704] [client 80.155.182.27:56585] [host test2.example.de] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\RouteMatch' not found in /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/Segment.php:388\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php(319): Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\Segment->match(Object(Zend\\Http\\PhpEnvironment\\Request), 16, Array)\n#1 /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/RouteListener.php(45): Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\TreeRouteStack->match(Object(Zend\\Http\\PhpEnvironment\\Request))\n#2 [internal function]: Zend\\Mvc\\RouteListener->onRoute(Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent))\n#3 /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent))\n#4 /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners('route', Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))\n#5 /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(319): Zend\\Even in /home/examplede/test2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/Segment.php on line 388\n, referer: https://test2.example.de/setup/
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP 7.2.13

Comment: Did you see in your server error log for any information?

Comment: See if you can troubleshoot from this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_install-main.html

Comment: @RajMohanR, I updated my post with an error which I found